# Align lines with opening and closing brackets

Tags: java, eclipse, code-formatting, eclipse-formatter

### Problem

I would like the **lines** with a **closing** brace/bracket/parenthesis to have exactly the same **indent** as the **lines** with the **matching opening** brace/bracket/parenthesis.

After some searching I guess that my needs are quite peculiar, but perhaps I'm just missing something. Is it possible to configure Eclipse auto-formatter to behave in such fashion? (I spent hours toggling checkboxes, but couldn't make it behave this way, so far.)

### Example

In other words, I would Eclipse to format this:

```java
public String concatenate(String a,
        String b) {
    ...
}
```

in this way:

```java
public String concatenate(
    String a, String b
) {
    ...
}

// The same, but with some extra comments:

public String concatenate( // the line with "(" has no indent
    String a, String b
) { // so, the line with the matching ")" also should not
    ...
} // same goes for {} and []
```

Comment: why?  no language uses that format as a standard?

Comment: Despite the fact that I couldn't imagine ever using this exact style, I think this is a worthwhile question because we might learn something about how far you can go to customize Eclipse formatting, and how you would accomplish that.

Comment: Why do you have to adulterate java's nice code formatting convention adopted by IDE like eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you should be able to do this in the Eclipse Neon Milestone 7 release (4.6M7) which has additions to the code formatter (see the 'New options for code formatter' section in the [What's New and Noteworthy](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.6/M7/) for the release).

Note: Milestone releases are early releases of Eclipse releases and might not be as stable as the final release (Eclipse Neon is due for release in June 2016).

Comment: Indeed! [This](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.6/M7/images/formatter-parentheses.png) looks exactly the way I wanted! Thanks :)